# Change password policy for Domain Administrator only

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have deployed a test environment which has a root domain controller (test.gr) and three sub-domains - gr.test.gr, cy.test.gr and us.test.gr

After a few weeks, I tried to log on to the FRDC as the Domain Administrator and I was asked to change the password, which I did.

However, I want to disable the complexity policies for the administrator password in order to set the original password and keep it permanently.

Is there any way to do this? I tried from GPMC.msc but it seems that this influences the users complexity and not the domain admin's.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, yes, what you want is possible.

The phrase you're looking for is "Fine Grained Password Policy" which allows you to configure password policies based on Global Security Group membership.

Be warned, though, while it's not *too* *complicated*, it isn't a process that's as slick as other areas of Active Directory.

I try and avoid posting blind links, but there's probably too much to put into an answer here so here is a walkthrough:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2007/10/06/windows-server-2008-fine-grained-password-policy-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for the immediate answer. I'll try what the article says and get back to you.